# Using XMLHTTP in Excel VBA to download website's table not working

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to download a table of historical gold prices from the following website:
[www.lbma.org.uk/prices-and-data/precious-metal-prices#/table](http://www.lbma.org.uk/prices-and-data/precious-metal-prices#/table)

```
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 
Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

With http
     .Open "GET", "https://www.lbma.org.uk/prices-and-data/precious-metal-prices#/table", True 
     .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
     .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
     .send

     Do  ' Wait till the page is loaded
        DoEvents
        Sleep (1)
    Loop Until .ReadyState = 4
End With
```

http.responseText is 115kB long and has all the text from the page etc., but none of the actual table with the gold price data. I am pretty new to xmlhttp - any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The approach you're using works for pages where the content you want is included in the page source: pages where content is created in the browser after the page has been served generally need a different approach. You can try automating IE or look at Selenium Basic.

Comment: I'm also seeing that the "export to xlsx" address can be generated by encoding some headers into URL format. Which would let you half-way automate the downloading of recent data into xlsx files, which you could then open and copy data from using VBA. Here's the decoded URL: `https://prices.lbma.org.uk/export/xls/?c={"metals":["gold"],"type":"daily","currency":["usd","gbp","eur"],"published":["am","pm"],"dates":{"start":"2021-01-01","end":"2021-10-05"}}`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to avoid IE11 as I find it utterly hopeless from VBA and it is all but obsolete anyway. Regarding the URL (well worked out!), but I need it fully automated and can't see how to get Excel to "press Save". I could use AutoIt I guess but it's getting a bit long winded (= unreliable)

Comment: @drb01  Do you want to be able to choose the dates for which the data is downloaded? If yes then the URL method seems to be the way to do it. As for "pressing save" you don't even really need that. VBA will download the excel file in the background, copy the data of interest, close the downloaded excel file and paste the data to **your** excel file. If you don't care about choosing the date, then the website returns a **huge** JSON response with all the data from 1968 until today. Of course once it's downloaded you can still get the dates you need but it'll take a while...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach to pull the AM prices only, this should be easily extended to pull PM prices if you so desire.

What I did was review the `XHR` requests made on this site and noticed it uses JSON to send data to the page for prices for each section. This is likely why you aren't finding the table HTML on the page, it's being created.

In order for this code you'll need to load up the `VBA-JSON` project. This is used to parse the JSON, you can find that [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). Follow the instructions on that page to get that added

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetHistoricalGoldPricesJSON() As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHand:
    Const url As String = "https://prices.lbma.org.uk/json/gold_am.json?r=166366104"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
         .Open "GET", url, False
         .send
         GetHistoricalGoldPricesJSON = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    Exit Function
    
ErrHand:
    GetHistoricalGoldPricesJSON = ""
End Function

Public Function GetGoldPricesJSON(JsonString As String) As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    If JsonString = "" Then
        Set GetGoldPricesJSON= Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set GetGoldPricesJSON= JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonString)
End Function

Public Sub GetGoldPrices()
    Dim GoldPrices As Object: Set GoldPrices = GetGoldPricesJSON(GetHistoricalGoldPricesJSON())
    
    'Nothing found or there was an error
    If GoldPrices Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim GoldPrice  As Variant
    Dim GoldArray  As Variant
    Dim Price      As Variant: ReDim GoldArray(1 To 50000, 1 To 4)
    Dim i          As Long
    
    For Each GoldPrice In GoldPrices
        i = i + 1
        GoldArray(i, 1) = GoldPrice("d")
        GoldArray(i, 2) = GoldPrice("v")(1)
        GoldArray(i, 3) = GoldPrice("v")(2)
        GoldArray(i, 4) = GoldPrice("v")(3)
    Next
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("Date", "USD AM Price", "GBP AM Price", "EUR AM Price")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(i + 1, 4)) = GoldArray
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That's incredible! But out of interest, and in case it changes in the future, how did you work out the URL "https://prices.lbma.org.uk/json/gold_am.json?r=166366104"

Comment: @drb01 I looked at the web traffic and figured out how the page worked. You can view web requests being exchanged the server and your browser in the dev tools, usually on the Network tab.

Comment: Got it. And any idea what the ?r=166366104 does? It doesn't seem to make much difference if I change it to say ?r=1.

Comment: Not entirely sure, could be used for tracking.